# why doesn't my python pandas dataframe strip method work for trailing whitespace? and how do I fix it?

Tags: python, pandas, removing-whitespace

I have this code to strip whitespace from the dataframe

```
# create a dataframe with 3 columns
dataFrame = pd.DataFrame({
   'Product Category': [' Computer', ' Mobile Phone', 'Electronics ', 'Appliances', ' Furniture', 'Stationery'],'Product Name': ['Keyboard', 'Charger', ' SmartTV', 'Refrigerators', ' Chairs', 'Diaries'],'Quantity': [10, 50, 10, 20, 25, 50]})

print ("Dataframe before removing whitespaces...\n",dataFrame)

# removing whitespace from more than 1 column
dataFrame['Product Category'].str.strip()
dataFrame['Product Name'].str.strip()

# dataframe
print ("Dataframe after removing whitespaces...\n",dataFrame)
```

The Dataframe before removing whitespace...

```
 Product Category   Product Name  Quantity
0         Computer       Keyboard        10
1     Mobile Phone        Charger        50
2     Electronics         SmartTV        10
3       Appliances  Refrigerators        20
4        Furniture         Chairs        25
5       Stationery        Diaries        50
```

The Dataframe after removing whitespace...

```
   Product Category   Product Name  Quantity
0         Computer       Keyboard        10
1     Mobile Phone        Charger        50
2     Electronics         SmartTV        10
3       Appliances  Refrigerators        20
4        Furniture         Chairs        25
5       Stationery        Diaries        50
```

The whitespace after "Electronics" is not stripped. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: You need to reassign it back to the column :) i.e `dataFrame['Product Category'] = dataFrame['Product Category'].str.strip()`

Answer (score 0):

As Umar said you need to do something like this:

```
# create a dataframe with 3 columns
dataFrame = pd.DataFrame({
   'Product Category': [' Computer', ' Mobile Phone', 'Electronics ', 'Appliances', ' Furniture', 'Stationery'],'Product Name': ['Keyboard', 'Charger', ' SmartTV', 'Refrigerators', ' Chairs', 'Diaries'],'Quantity': [10, 50, 10, 20, 25, 50]})

print ("Dataframe before removing whitespaces...\n",dataFrame)

# removing whitespace from more than 1 column
dataFrame['Product Category'] = dataFrame['Product Category'].str.strip()
dataFrame['Product Name'] = dataFrame['Product Name'].str.strip()

# dataframe
print ("Dataframe after removing whitespaces...\n",dataFrame)
```